# CodeIgniter Session encryption_key

Tags: codeigniter, session

In a CI application to use session it have to used like that
    $config['encryption_key'] = "something"
can i use without set anything in between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. If you open up the Session core library it has this:

```
if ($this->encryption_key == '')
{
     show_error('In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.');
}
```

There is no real reason to not have it, so I'd just leave it in there. If you want, just make it a single letter but even this is not advised.